# Approximation for the Marcum Q-function

Tags: integration, special-functions, approximate-integration

I want to approximate the Marcum Q-function $Q_{m}(a,b)$ when $b$ goes to zero, where the Marcum Q-function $Q_{m}(a,b)$ is defined in an integral form, shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function

Comment: What's wrong with the provided series expansions in the Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that all three parameters are positive. We know that the integral over $[0, \infty)$ is $1$. The integral over $[0, b]$ can be evaluated termwise:
$$e^{-x^2/2} I_{m - 1}(a x) =
\frac {\left( \frac {a x} 2 \right)^{m - 1}} {(m - 1)!}
 \sum_{n \geq 0}
  \frac {(-1)^n} {n!} \hspace {1px}
  {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1} {\left( -n; m; \frac {a^2} 2 \right)}
  \left( \frac {x^2} {2} \right)^{\! n}, \\
Q_m(a, b) = 1 - \frac {e^{-a^2/2}} {(m - 1)!} \sum_{n \geq 0}
 \frac {(-1)^n} {(n + m) n!} \hspace {1px}
 {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1} {\left( -n; m; \frac {a^2} 2 \right)}
 \left( \frac {b^2} 2 \right)^{\! n + m}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, could you give me some more details about those two equations? I cannot understand how to derive.

Comment: Take the series expansions for $\exp$ and for $I_m$ and multiply them. The sum giving the $n$th term of the product happens to be a hypergeometric series because
$$\frac {(-1)^k} {(m + k - 1)! \, (n - k)!} =
\frac {(-n)_k} {(m - 1)! \, n! \, (m)_k}.$$
Then substitute the expansion into the integral form of $Q_m$.

Comment: Thank you very much!